# Display information on Google Maps marker

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the information that is saved in the firebase real-time database and display them on a map using the Google Maps API.

This is my firebase

[image: firebase]

This is my marker on map

[image: web map]

Right now it opens and shows the users current location and it syncs the lat and long coordinates to the firebase real-time database using Geofire.

Now I can retrieve information from firebase and display it on the map but if I add another user,  the information is still same. Why?

This is the code I have so far:

```
// This Function will  add/display that marker on the map
function AddDriver(data) {


  var LatLng = new 
    google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(data.val().lat),parseFloat(data.val().lng 
    ));
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    //title:service,
    position:LatLng,
    map: map
  });



  // Attach it to the marker we've just added
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    getData();
  });

  markers[data.key] = marker; // add marker in the markers 
  array...
    document.getElementById("loc").innerHTML = loc_count;


  function getData(){
    var locationsRef = 
      firebase.database().ref('Locations/oEyL4QXg1XYAABIBGPvqYbzlNiv2');

    console.log(locationsRef);
    locationsRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        console.log(childData);
        var contentString = childData;
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: contentString
        });
        infowindow.open(map,marker);

      });
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Firebase Document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data)

you are using `locationsRef.once` that will notify you an only single time data changed

i think you have to use something like  [ValueEventListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ValueEventListener) that will notify you when any changes happen 
in your snapshot